# Rigorous Proof on Malicious Zero-Knowledge Property of Schnorr Protocol

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, schnorr-identification, zero-knowledge, interactive-proofs

Let us recall the ***Schnorr Protocol***, following Chris Peikert's excellent Notes on the [*Theory of Cryptography*](https://github.com/cpeikert/TheoryOfCryptography/blob/master/lec18%20-%20Proofs%20of%20Knowledge.pdf).

**Protocol.** Let $G=\langle g \rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $q$. We consider an arbitrary element $x\in G$, having Discrete Logarithm $w=:\log_g(x)$. The input to the *Prover* $P$ is $x,w$ and to the *Verifier* $V$ is just $x$. The interactive Proof System is defined as follows:

[image]

My **Question** is on the **Zero-Knowledge Property** for a $\color{red}{\textrm{Malicious Verifier $V^*$}}$.

So, in the same Set of Notes, we define a simulator $S^{V^*}$ as follows:

**$\underline{\text{Simulator $S^{V^*}(x)$}}$**

REPEAT

- $b \stackrel{\\\\\$}{\leftarrow}\{0,1\} \ ; \ a \stackrel{\\\\\$}{\leftarrow} G$
- $z\leftarrow g^a x^{-b}$
- $b' \stackrel{}{\leftarrow} V^*(z)$

UNTIL $(b'=b)$

RETURN $(z,b,a)$

I would be more than grateful if someone could *rigorously* show why this distribution, $S^{V^*}(x)$, is indistinguishable from the distribution $\mathrm{VIEW}_{(P,V^*)}^{V^*}(x)$ and what kind of indistinguishability we have.

It is noticeable that I couldn't find anywhere on the Internet a rigorous Proof for the Mailicious Verifier Case, but only for the Honest Verifier Zero-Knowledge (HVZK). Is that so easy that it is ommited?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's wait  [Chris Peikert](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/14958/chris-peikert) to answer this?

Comment: Sure, this will be great! However everyone who can show how to calculate this probability using the repeat statement in the algorithm, is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be overthinking the result? The key here is that the simulator has a very powerful advantage, which is that it can *rewind* $V^\ast$, that is, running with many inputs as much as it wants, until something happens.

With this in mind, note that in the simulated execution $(z,b,a)$ is distributed as:

- $b$ random
- $a$ random
- $z$ constrained to $z = g^ax^{-b}$.

In the real world, the tuple is distributed as:

- $b$ random
- $z$ random
- $a$ constrained to $a = r+bw$.

Both triples have exactly the same distribution. There are different ways to see this, some more formal than the others. Intuitively, it's a combination of the following two things:

1. $z = g^ax^{-b}$ if and only if the discrete log $r$ of $z$ is $a -bw$, that is, $r = a-bw$
2. Sampling $r$ at random and letting $a = r+bw$ leads to the same distribution for the tuple $(a,r)$ than first sampling $a$ and then letting $r = a-bw$.

If you want to prove this even more formally maybe it's useful to see why the one-time-pad is perfectly secure; it's the same proof.

Comment: Dear Daniel, many thanks for the answer. I already had this intuition, and this exactly why I posted here the question. It would be more than nice if you could provide a rigorous proof --it may help a lot of people! :)